# Tesseract OCR training gives 'APPLY_BOXES' errors

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm training Tesseract 3 for the digital-7 font, and I'm getting some errors in the output (from stderr):

```
APPLY_BOXES: boxfile line 35/I ((735,7860),(737,7890)): FAILURE! Couldn't find a matching blob
```

And

```
APPLY_BOXES: Unlabelled word at :Bounding box=(7523,-910)->(7549,-906)
```

What do they mean?

The command line I'm using is:

```
tesseract eng.digital-7.exp0.tif eng.digital-7.exp0 nobatch box.train
```

Comment: were u successful in training the digital 7 font? i have similar requirement. Kindly let me know ur experience in tesseract. Im facing same problem as you

Comment: Yes, I succeeded in training it, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 4):

Double check your .tif file character spacing: the first error could be caused by two characters being too close, and producing one single bounding box (see also this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=698)).

The second error is a consequence of the first one, I suppose.